# Looping in powershell with 2 foreach

Tags: powershell, csv

I am needing to write a script which will delete files in both a folder for a computer and files in user folders on each of those computers.  I have most of the script written but I am having issues with looping two of the foreach statements

```
#Get Computer List
$computers = "C:\Temp\ComputerList.csv"

#Delete Temp Folder Files
foreach (computer in $computers) {
        Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Temp\*" -Recurse -Force
}

#Create list of users from C:\users
Import-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\ComputerList.csv" | foreach {
        dir c:\users | select Name | Export-CSV -Path "C:\temp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}

$list = import-csv -Path "C:\temp\users.csv

#Delete Chrome Cache
taskkill /f /im "chrome.exe"
start-sleep -seconds 5
$Items = @('Archived History',
           'Cache\*',
           'Cookies',
           'History',
           'Login Data',
           'Top Sites',
           'Visited Links',
           'Web Data')
$Folder = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
$Items | % {
        if (Test-Path "$Folder\$_") {
            Remove-Item "Folder\$_"
        }
}

#Delete Internet Explorer Cache
Import-CSV -Path C:\temp\users.csv | foreach {
        Remove-Item -Path "C:\users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
}

#Delete Firefox Cache
Import-CSV -Path C:\temp\users.csv | foreach {
        Remove-Item -Path 
        "C:\users\$($_.name)\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\*" -Recurse 
        -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -Path 
        "C:\users\$($_.name)\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\*.*" - 
        Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -Path 
   "C:\users\$($_.name)\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cache2\entries\*.*" 
        -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -Path 
         "C:\users\$($_.name)\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\thumbnails\*" 
        -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -Path 
       "C:\users\$($_.name)\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cookies.sqlite" 
        -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -Path 
   "C:\users\$($_.name)\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\webappstore.sqlite" 
       -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Remove-Item -Path 
"C:\users\$($_.name)\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\chromeappstore.sqlite" 
       -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
}
```

Is there a way that I can get everything to run for each machine and each user profile on that machine and output the results, specifically whether it succeeded or if it error'd out.

How would I write the output log for something like this so that I can go back through and see what worked and what didnt?

I know that some of my code is redundant so I apologize ahead of time.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should either invoke the command to remove the files in the path, or provide the UNC. As of now, you're not doing either if it's to be removing files for a remote computer. Lemme get home and I'll assist with this. You're definitely right as well, a lot of this is redundant.

Comment: Im home, are you performing this in a domain environment?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes this is all being done in a domain environment.  I am off for the day but picking it back up in the morning.  Im going to try and make some changes to my script and then update the changes here and see if it looks better.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would take a different approach, seeing if this may be a repetitive task, I would turn it into a function with something along the lines like this:

```
#$computers = "C:\Temp\ComputerList.csv"
Function Clear-BrowserCache {
    Param (

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeLineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String[]]$ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [String[]]$UserName

    )

    Begin {
    
    $Log_Path = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "Log Exports"
    $Log_Name = 'BrowserCache_Deletion' + '.csv'
    
    $Start_Time = Get-Date -Format G
    
    }

    Process {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            try {

                $PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -EnableNetworkAccess -ErrorAction Stop
                
                $User_List = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Directory | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending } -Session $PSSession 

                    foreach ($user in $User_List) {

                        $User_Name    = Find-User -UserName $User
                        $User_Profile = $User.Name

                        $FireFox_Path = "C:\Users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla"
                        $Chrome_Path  = "C:\Users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
                        $IE_Path      = "C:\Users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*"

                        
                        $FireFox_PathTest = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Test-Path -Path $using:FireFox_Path -PathType Container } -Session $PSSession
                        $Chrome_PathTest  = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Test-Path -Path $using:Chrome_Path -PathType Container } -Session $PSSession
                        $IE_PathTest      = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Test-Path -Path $using:FireFox_Path -PathType Any } -Session $PSSession

                            #region Firefox
                            if ($FireFox_Path -eq $true) {
                            
                                $FireFox_Bool = $true

                                $FireFox_List = @( "C:\users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\*",
                                                   "C:\users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cache2\entries\*",
                                                   "C:\users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\thumbnails\*",
                                                   "C:\users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cookies.sqlite",
                                                   "C:\users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\webappstore.sqlite",
                                                   "C:\users\$User_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\chromeappstore.sqlite"
                                )

                                
                                $Fox_Process = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Name firefox -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } -Session $PSSession
                                    if ($null -ne $Fox_Process) {
                                        
                                        $null = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Name firefox | Stop-Process -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } -Session $PSSession


                                        foreach ($FF_Path in $FireFox_List) {
                                            switch (Test-Path -Path $FF_Path) {
  
                                              $true  { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Remove-Item -Path $using:FF_Path -Recurse } -Session $PSSession  }
                                              $false { "Path Doesn't exist `n`t$FF_Path" }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            else {
                                
                                $FireFox_Bool = $false

                            }
                            #endregion Firefox

                        [PSCustomObject]@{

                            'Computer Name'   = $Computer 
                            'User Name'       = $User_Name
                            'Firefox Cleared' = $FireFox_Bool

                        } # | Export-Csv -Path $Log_Name -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation
                    }

            } Catch [System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException] {
                
                #$Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName - To get this exception
                #in order to 'catch' the error ( .NET Exception )
                $Error[0].Exception.Message

            }

        }
    
    }

    End {

      Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    }
} 



Function Find-User {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$UserName
    )
    Begin {

        try {


            $User = [ADSISeacher]"samaccountname=$UserName"
            $UserProperties  = $User.FindOne().Properties
            $UserDisplayName = $UserProperties.displayname 

        } Catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] {

            $UserDisplayName = $UserName
            
        }
    }

    End {

        $UserDisplayName

    }
}

 
# SIG # Begin signature block
# MIID8wYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIID5DCCA+ACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMGkGCisGAQQB
# gjcCAQSgWzBZMDQGCisGAQQBgjcCAR4wJgIDAQAABBAfzDtgWUsITrck0sYpfvNR
# AgEAAgEAAgEAAgEAAgEAMCEwCQYFKw4DAhoFAAQUytRTDxUvPNpy4d1nT0Nll5fu
# 3M2gggILMIICBzCCAXCgAwIBAgIQUBW8X0Yzy6FEY17ozWzLSzANBgkqhkiG9w0B
# AQUFADAeMRwwGgYDVQQDDBNEZWxldGUtQnJvd3NlckNhY2hlMB4XDTIxMDYxMDAw
# MDMxOVoXDTI1MDYxMDAwMDAwMFowHjEcMBoGA1UEAwwTRGVsZXRlLUJyb3dzZXJD
# YWNoZTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEArmzAJSlDnDd7oXitfv2m
# rkgo2KIwUf+9mQdUNQYl4kmYQY8dpMzcugxf/TrXkzWH9o5MQrJ4fbZHcJVqI+uc
# TjqNpFnp6k55bBtDCjql8Mrf/gIDi8ej08kLTBwmQZW6BvXNfTikRK78whR79PBU
# eR1Vi5U+ibuiL8eInYjIjlECAwEAAaNGMEQwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwMw
# HQYDVR0OBBYEFO19PFJIojssZEIxu/e++3fdsBi4MA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDAN
# BgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQCdG29Gomhx1E+mMy3kQSOff67bH2KJBx7/14ekAwxj
# V2/sM1HSEYtwTt4I/qLD/MLlNLedVGlsM4HfTfOpEG1T+QmAPPdIsG2BbqQP8eoA
# gHQcoie+06zTr/Ue7ZqVCaVwkmYrG726Xe83pEcI5YRo0fiW2SDo6p38XgQhNdi1
# ozGCAVIwggFOAgEBMDIwHjEcMBoGA1UEAwwTRGVsZXRlLUJyb3dzZXJDYWNoZQIQ
# UBW8X0Yzy6FEY17ozWzLSzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoHgwGAYKKwYBBAGCNwIBDDEKMAig
# AoAAoQKAADAZBgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxDAYKKwYBBAGCNwIBBDAcBgorBgEEAYI3AgEL
# MQ4wDAYKKwYBBAGCNwIBFTAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQUL83kuZoYz71YjNWmSfhr
# JeO+l3owDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEgYB2/oazr3wXTZaR0UbSH0bMOXBKcENfUJ4Q
# SIW1WLIfNON+5gRBk1nTHRI1iWnFbiy2iG5KWcGAOr7AoC7kZEb6vcWAyGY6yHFn
# wmI6XS0MUuxD/UqMWukOynqzVkHM8BakJtVUi2XB2aT3zWKbPsSU7LIU0pRwvhCy
# b2xtU+yK4g==
# SIG # End signature block
```

The concept is there, and the function would be called like:

- `Clear-BrowserCache -ComputerName ComputerOne`
- `Clear-BrowserCache -ComputerName (Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\Comps.txt)`
- `Import-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\ComputerList.csv" | Clear-BrowserCache`

Of course, this was a quick example I whipped up, but hopefully you get the concept im trying to bring across. I do recommend *"neat typing"* which just helps you in the long run. I also left out Chrome, and IE which could easily be added, and displayed as a `bool` value on the `PSCustomObject`, with an option to export for logging. Theres a parameter of `-UserName` which could also be used with a thought-process of: *"I just want to clear one profile, and not everyone elses."*, so maybe you can work up the rest of the code to skip the regular protocol to remove all browser cache from all users, and have it just do one.

You're also missing a lot of basics such as remoting basics. I bring this up due to you looking to run the script against remote computers without the *infrastructure* to support remote systems. This should help you understand the concept of what should be done in order for a task like this to be accomplished. Due note, UNC paths could've been used as well, it's just a slower process. Also, *pinging* a computer isn't my favorites way to test a computer, since we can get an echo reply, doesn't necessarily mean you can connect to it. `New-PSSession` is a better alternative to this in my opinion. Also, sessions is a preferred method when doing multiple tasks like this since we don't want to constantly close, and re-open a remote session, it can become *computationally expensive*.

Result would be:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Clear-BrowserCache -ComputerName localhost

Computer Name User Name Firefox Cleared
------------- --------- ---------------
localhost     UserTwo             False
localhost     UserOne             False
localhost     Abraham             False
localhost     Public              False
```

*Added a sig-block just in case you're restricted to remote signed. This script also was **NOT** tested in an actual production environment, use at your own risk; or on a single 'test' computer.*