# How to run multiple scripts using text files full of references

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I feel that I am close to being ready to run but need some help fine tuning things.

My primary objective is this:

From each text file (named after the computer it was generated from), run each script using the data that exists within the .txt file.  Each file is output from the C:\Users folder on the computer, listing each user profile that exists on that machine.  I need to be able to run the script so that it deletes the specified folders/files for each user profile on that machine.

```
# Name: CacheCleanup
# Description: Deletes cache files per user on each computer
# Syntax: .\CacheCleanup.ps1
# Author: Nicholas Nedrow
# Created: 06/15/2021




#Text file contains list of all machines that have recently pinged and are online
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\CacheCleanUp\ComputerUp.txt"

#Users are listed in individual text files assigned with the name of their PC.
$Users = Get-Content "C:\Temp\CacheCleanUp\Computer Users\*.txt"

#Base path for deletion paths
$Path = "\\$PC\c$\users\$user\appdata\local"

#Delete User\Temp files
Remote-Item -Path "$Path\temp\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose

#Delete Teams files
Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Microsoft\Teams" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
Remove-ITem -Path "$Path\Microosft\TeamsMeetingAddin" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Microsoft\TeamsPresenceAddin" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose

#Delete Chrome Cache
Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose

#Delete IE Cache
Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose


#Delete Firefox cache
 Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
 Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\*.*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
 Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cache2\entries\*.*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
 Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\thumbnails\*" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
 Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cookies.sqlite" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
 Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\webappstore.sqlite" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
 Remove-Item -Path "$Path\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\chromeapstore.sqlite" -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose


#How to Run each script for each user on each machine
#How to generate detailed log with results of deletion for each section
```

I will state right away that I am still learning scripting and am unfamiliar with functions, even though I am pretty sure that is what I need to develop here.  This is a domain network so the appropriate path for the computer name has been taken into consideration.  Each script does run independently, with the computer name specified but I run into issues when it comes to trying to call out each user profile on that computer.

If possible, it would be nice to have some sort of generated report with the outcome of each user profile and what was ran successfully.  I don't need to necessarily know every file that was deleted but maybe a list of those files that were unable to be deleted due to conflicts with running programs or permission issues.

Comment: Hello, I made a similar function to what you're trying to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912623/looping-in-powershell-with-2-foreach/67914725#67914725. never finished it completely as it was just a response to the users question. Hopefully this helps in what you're looking to do. Not necessarily answering your question tho, just thought I'd share.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I thought your name looked familiar.  I forgot that I posted that question when I first started this project.  This is the newest edition of the project script that I have come up with.  I cleaned up a bunch of the taskings that need to be done to try and simplify it down a little bit.  I did look at your response in that other post but never got a chance to test it out in our environment.

Comment: Ahhh, didn't realize that was you lol. You can easily add the other cached locations and it should check every users profile just given the computer name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use loops. Consider the following code:

```
$configFiles = "C:\Temp\CacheCleanUp";

Get-Content "$configFiles\TESTComputers.txt" | % {
    $PC = $_;
    Write-Host "Attempting to clean cache on computer: $PC";

    Get-Content "$configFiles\TESTusers.txt" | % {
        $user = $_;
        $Path = "\\$PC\c$\users\$user\appdata\local"
        Write-Host "`tCleaning $Path"
        <# Your code goes here #>
    }    
}
```

TESTusers.txt contains:

```
dave
bob
amy
```

TESTComputers.txt contains:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
10.0.0.5
```

This is the output of the above code and computer/user files:

```
Attempting to clean cache on computer: 10.0.0.1
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.1\c$\users\dave\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.1\c$\users\bob\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.1\c$\users\amy\appdata\local
Attempting to clean cache on computer: 10.0.0.2
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.2\c$\users\dave\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.2\c$\users\bob\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.2\c$\users\amy\appdata\local
Attempting to clean cache on computer: 10.0.0.3
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.3\c$\users\dave\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.3\c$\users\bob\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.3\c$\users\amy\appdata\local
Attempting to clean cache on computer: 10.0.0.4
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.4\c$\users\dave\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.4\c$\users\bob\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.4\c$\users\amy\appdata\local
Attempting to clean cache on computer: 10.0.0.5
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.5\c$\users\dave\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.5\c$\users\bob\appdata\local
    Cleaning \\10.0.0.5\c$\users\amy\appdata\local
```

Few things to note about the code:

1. `Get-Content "filename" | %`  - this is going to loop through the contents of the file one line at a time. `%` is a shortcut for [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1).
2. `$_` when inside a foreach loop is an automatic variable created by PowerShell that contains the current item in the loop.
3. If you have a loop inside a loop and you need to access both `$_` values from the inner and outer loop, you can create a new variable (eg `$PC = $_;`) in the outer loop that can be used within the inner loop (eg `$Path = "\\$PC\c$\users\$user\appdata\local"`).

You should definitely [learn to use functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.1), and then in the future you can combine functions into modules. This is a big help in organising your code, and you can avoid duplication by sharing functions between different scripts - but your current script doesnt *need* functions (but theyre a good idea).

---

Depending on your network, you might be able to use PowerShell remoting instead of the Administrative shares to achieve the same effect. This is a more advanced topic, there is some configuration required on the machines you want to connect but the advantage is your computer sends the script to each target, and the target computer runs the script and reports its results.

Another possible change i would suggest is only using a list of computers - then on each computer use `get-childitem -path c:\users` to actually get the list of each profile currently on that target computer.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome response.  A lot of great info in there.  I did have a question, when you mentioned the get-childitem for the list of users on the machine.  would that be something that I could use $path for instead of having to type it out?  Also, would that need to just be a one time reference or would that need to happen for each action item within the body of the script.

Comment: You can use get-childitem like get-content and pipe the output into a foreach loop. Not sure if this will work on the administrative shares(might only work with powershell remoting) you will need to test.  `get-childitem -path c:\users | % {$_.FullName; <#Do Stuff in here #>}`.  (Note: `$_` from Get-ChildItem has lots of properties besides FullName - change `$_.FullName` to `$_ | Get-Member` to list available properties on `$_`).